# Create array of custom domain postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

Because of the inherit limitations of enum (you can't add values to the enum from within a function), I'm switching to custom domains with a check constraint verifying the values. I need to be able to create arrays of my custom enums, but when I try something like this:

```
CREATE DOMAIN foo AS text CHECK (VALUE IN ('foo', 'bar'));
CREATE TABLE foo_table(foo_column foo[]);
```

I get the error

```
type "foo[]" does not exist
```

Doing some googling, I found [this from 2004](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1082462005.57436.102.camel@jester) which made it look like support for this was coming. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

#### UPDATE

I've come up with a hacky solution, which I'll put as the answer if no one comes up with a better solution in a few days. This solution means you can't reuse a type to be an array, you have to create a separate type that acts as the array:

```
CREATE DOMAIN foo_group AS text[] CHECK (VALUE <@ ARRAY['foo', 'bar']);

CREATE TABLE foo_table(foo_column foo_group);
```

The following work:

```
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(ARRAY['foo']);
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(ARRAY['foo', 'bar']);
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(ARRAY['bar']);
```

The following don't:

```
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(ARRAY['foo', 'baz']);
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(ARRAY['baz']);
```

Comment: `CREATE DOMAIN foo_group AS text[] CHECK (VALUE <@ ARRAY['foo', 'bar']);` - without additional function. [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: That's awesome. Didn't know range operators worked for arrays like that

Comment: It is not "range operator". There are several operators with the same notation for different types of arguments. Execute `\do+ <@` in the `psql`.

Comment: Ah, so `arraycontained(left, right)` would have worked as well. Was looking for something like that on the array functions page, guess I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround is:

```
CREATE TYPE foo_tup AS (item foo);
```

Domain types can wrapped in tuples like this and that gives you an array constructor.  The downside is now you probably want to create casts:

```
select array[row('foo')::foo_tup, row('bar')];
```

For example you could create a function and a cast:

```
create function foo_tup(foo) returns foo_tup language sql as $$
    select row($1)::foo_tup;
$$ immutable;
create function foo(foo_tup) returns foo language sql as $$
     select $1.item;
$$;
create cast (foo as foo_tup) with function foo_tup(foo);
create cast (foo_tup as foo) with function foo(foo_tup);
```

Then aggregation becomes easy:

```
select array_agg(myfoo::foo_tup) from my_table;
```

though you get extra parentheses.