# Custom domain array by recurrency of custom domain

Tags: postgresql, sql-domain

Documentation [*say nothing*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) about create a domain from other custom domains.

I need only to create array of (previously created) custom domains, so it is **not** the [problem/solution discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43259089/287948).

Example:

```
CREATE DOMAIN jbag AS JSONb
  CHECK(  VALUE IS NULL OR  jsonb_typeof(VALUE) IN ('object','null')  );
```

But PostgreSQL not accepting declations like `CREATE FUNCTION intersection(jbag[]) RETURNS jbag`.

How to do a kind of `CREATE DOMAIN jbag[] AS jbag[]`?... Or say to postgresql-parser "hello let's accept arrays of atomic custom types!"?

---

For details see [bag.sql](https://github.com/datasets-br/sql-json-bags/blob/master/bag.sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a domain based on a predefined array type, in this case on `jsonb[].` 
Define a check constraint using a function which ensures that all array elements are compatible with `jbag`:

```
create or replace function jbags_check(jsonb[])
returns boolean language sql immutable as $$
    select bool_and(elem is null or jsonb_typeof(elem) in ('object','null'))
    from unnest($1) u(elem);
$$;

create domain jbags as jsonb[] 
    check(jbags_check(value));
```

Now your function may look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION intersection(jbags) RETURNS jbag AS $f$
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(e,m::int)::jbag
    FROM (
      SELECT e, MIN(m) AS m
        FROM unnest($1), jsonb_each_text(unnest) as a(e, m)
        GROUP BY e
        HAVING COUNT(*)=array_length($1,1)
    ) t
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

The function in action:

```
select intersection(array['{"a": 2}', '{"a": 3, "b": 3}']::jbags);

 intersection 
--------------
 {"a": 2}
(1 row)
```

but:

```
select intersection(array['1', '{"a": 3, "b": 3}']::jbags);

ERROR:  value for domain jbags violates check constraint "jbags_check"
```

Comment: Thanks again Klin!  Well, bad news for me about PostgreSQL (all versions!?)... So, is it?... **PostgreSQL Domain is ugly**, no reuse or  recurrency in custom datatypes. Your solution, of course, is valid and seems the only way... I just did not believe that PostgreSQL Domain was so poor: non-elegant and difficult to extend/generalize datatypes. PS: I'll wait another few days to see if no one gives a clue, before accept your answer.

Comment: The concept of domains is simple by design. On the other hand, you can get the desired effect in a relatively easy way.