# Are custom domains arrays possible in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, sql-domain

I have declared a custom domain `tmoney` as

```sql
create domain tmoney as decimal (13,4);
```

Then I use an array of it in a table declaration,

```sql
create table test (
  id        int generated by default as identity primary key,
  volume    smallint[5] not null default '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}',
  price     tmoney[5]   not null default '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}'
);

insert into test(volume, price) 
values ('{1, 10, 50, 100, 250}', '{10, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8.75}');
```

In PostgreSQL 12 there is no parsing exceptions, as it seems to have existed before (see [Create array of custom domain postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259089/create-array-of-custom-domain-postgres)), however, a DBCException is found whenever I try to retrieve the values inserted as tmoney[]. Note that this error does not occur with smallint[].

```sql
select * from test;

id|volume           |price                                        |
--|-----------------|---------------------------------------------|
 1|{1,10,50,100,250}|DBCException: Can't resolve data type _tmoney|
```

The documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html only specifies that

> tdata_type – The underlying data type of the domain. This can include array specifiers.

This is consistent with a domain created as

```sql
create domain tmoney as decimal (13,4)[];

create table test (
  id        int generated by default as identity primary key,
  volume    smallint[5] not null default '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}',
  price     tmoney  not null default '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}'
);

insert into test(volume, price) 
values ('{1, 10, 50, 100, 250}', '{10, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8.75}');

select * from test;

id|volume           |price                   |
--|-----------------|------------------------|
 1|{1,10,50,100,250}|{10.0,9.75,9.5,9.0,8.75}|
```

However, as the PostgreSQL 12 parser does not prevent using `tmoney[5]` in a table declaration, I am wondering if there is a different syntax that allows me to use this first version of the custom domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using arrays of domains was [introduced in v11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.14.5.6).

Your SQL statements work just fine with `psql`.

You must be using a different client that probably doesn't support that properly.
Consider filing a bug report or enhancement request with that software.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe. I was using DBeaver. Yes, it works with `psql` as you said. Sad that DBeaver fails.

Comment: Done https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/9643

Comment: Today, the release of DBeaver v7.2.0 has fixed that bug.